# I am updating my state using this.setState but still i am recieving the old values in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

```
class EditLocation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super();
    this.state = {
      LocationId: '',
      locationOptions: [],
    }
    this.baseState = this.state;
    this.findLocationById = this.findLocationById.bind(this);

}
findLocationById = (locationId) => {
  let locationOptions = [];
  if (locationId <= 0) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState(this.baseState);
      locationOptions.push(
        <CustomInput
        type="checkbox"
        id={value.LocationTypeId}
        key={value.LocationTypeId}
        value={value.LocationTypeId}
        defaultChecked={false}
        label={`${value.LocationTypeName}`}
        className="mb-0"
        onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)}
      />
      )
      this.setState({locationOptions:locationOptions})
    },200)
    else {
      setTimeout(() => {
      let location = this.props.store.selectedLocation;
      this.props.store.LocationTypes.forEach((value)=>{
        if(location.LocationTypes ? 
         location.LocationTypes.includes(value.LocationTypeId): false)
        {
          locationOptions.push(
            <CustomInput
            type="checkbox"
            id={value.LocationTypeId}
            key={value.LocationTypeId}
            value={value.LocationTypeId}
            defaultChecked={true}
            label={`${value.LocationTypeName}`}
            className="mb-0"
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)}
          />
          )
        }
        else
        {
          locationOptions.push(
            <CustomInput
            type="checkbox"
            id={value.LocationTypeId}
            key={value.LocationTypeId}
            value={value.LocationTypeId}
            defaultChecked={false}
            label={`${value.LocationTypeName}`}
            className="mb-0"
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)}
          />
          )
        }
      })
    this.setState({
       LocationId: location.LocationId,
       locationOptions: locationOptions,
    })
   

   render(){
  return (
   <div>
    <Modal>
      <Form>
         <FormGroup>
           <input
            value={this.state.LocationId}
            type="text"
            name="Location"
            id="Location"      
           />
         </FormGroup>
         <FormGroup>
           {console.log(this.state.locationOptions)} // showing updated state value
           {this.state.locationOptions} // showing previous state.locationOptions value
         </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </Modal>
   </div>
   )
}

}
```

console.log() inside the render is updating the value by my checks on customInput are not updating. I need to either reopen the modal or reload the whole program to see updates.
Any solution and resources would be helpful as I am stuck at it for hours and can't seem to figure the issue. and store is mobx store if that helps

Comment: Don't console.log in the render, it's an unintentional side-effect. Use `componentDidUpdate` to log when state updates.

Comment: and the locationId is updated and shown as its updated inside the <input> but checkboxes are not working. I know the setState is async but I dont know how to achieve the real updates inside the render using its callback

Comment: @DrewReese but console.log is not the main concern. i need the {this.state.locationOptions} to show the actual value and how i achieve that

Comment: `this.state` is ***always*** the current state. You're also doing some weird stuff in `findLocationById ` like storing JSX in state (*a React anti-pattern*) which is an almost guarantee to have stale values in enclosures, and enqueueing state updates on a timeout, so who knows on which future render cycle you'll see that update.

Comment: is `findLocationById ` called below and also check syntax

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots this is not actual code and i m not allowed to share but the findLocationByid is called inside <Modal onOpened={()=>findLocationById(locationId}} >

Comment: I suspect this.setState(this.baseState);  Please check the state after this.

Comment: @DrewReese I am actually fairly new to reactjs and I dont know the best way to achieve that. I need to update checkbox values  based on the values I receive from store.selectedLocation. 
If you can guide me whats the best way to do it. That would be great. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: ok as there are limited code not able to find exact thing like `baseState` . also check whether function is binded.

Comment: this.baseState as the name suggests is just a plain copy of state in its initialState and its used for the Add new location part 
when the locationID is -1. i am setting the state to initial state. 
when the locationId is something. the state will be updated from values of store.selectedLocation and then render() would display them in JSX. 

@PrakashS thats the workflow of the problem but if you think I am messing somewhere, pls let me know. I am fairly new so I am actually having some difficulty in understanding the react render/update flow

Comment: i m updating the code in the question where is shows the binding and baseState part 
@Nithin-Techidiots

Comment: In your setState call where you use `LocationId: location.LocationId,` it looks like `location` doesn't exist in the current scope. You should also replace the duplicate checkbox code with something like `<CustomCheckBox checked={checked} {...value} />`

Comment: location is in the else { location } scope and so is the this.setState. i may have messed up the brackets in editing. the issue is that i am changin like 10 values in that 
this.setState calls and everything else is updating find expect the checkbox jsx. and i dont know how I can do that in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using setState in a wrong way.

> setState() **enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
> that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
> updated state**. This is the primary method you use to update the user
> interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

1. So it asynchronous and you can't guarantee when update happens.
2. Using setTimeout is a bad manners in React.
3. Storing whole components in state, e.g. *locationOptions* isn't good idea either.
4. Better to move input to separate component, as i see only *defaultChecked* different.
5. Better to use Hooks, easier to think about this in *React way*, it's require some time and effort to figure out how to write [declarative instead of imperative code](https://medium.com/@myung.kim287/declarative-vs-imperative-251ce99c6c44).

Can refactor a litle

```
// sync local state and props is a pain, better to avoid it
  //constructor(props) {
   //super(props);
    //const location = this.props.store.selectedLocation
   // this.state = {
      //LocationId: location.LocationId,
    //}
//}

 const location = this.props.store.selectedLocation;

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal>
                <Form>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <input
                            value={this.props.store.selectedLocation}
                            type="text"
                            name="Location"
                            id="Location"
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        {this.props.store.cationTypes.map((value) => (
                            <CustomInput
                                type="checkbox"
                                id={value.LocationTypeId}
                                key={value.LocationTypeId}
                                value={value.LocationTypeId}
                                defaultChecked={location.LocationTypes.includes(value.LocationTypeId)}
                                label={`${value.LocationTypeName}`}
                                className="mb-0"
                                onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)}
                            />}
                        ))
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: then what should be my method like. I have to fetch values for checkbox like name/id/checked status from store. It can be 4 or 10 checkboxes. What should be the best approach to achieve that without messing the update cycle. Thanks for your time though. much appreciated.

Comment: I updated the code as you Asked and It worked. Thank you so much for your help sir